# Disable editing of javascript from chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, javascript-security

So, I just noticed today that you can apparently run javascript in the chrome console. I had no idea you could do this. It's actually really cool.

In my rails app, I have an external javascript page. Some of the variables on that page I would like to be global so that all the functions in the JS file can access them. for example I have a map, and I would like the map object to be global in the javascript file because that way all my functions access the one map variable instead of creating their own, and I can break complex operations down into smaller functions.

This is all well and good I know how to do that and it's working perfectly. My problem now, can I protect the variables from outside? For example you can change the values of all the javascript class variables from the chrome console.. as well methods from for example the map are accessible and excecutable.. I have locked the map settings on one of the pages so it is not zoomable or movable, however from the console I can simply say `map.setZoom(11)` and the map will zoom to 11.. I can type `map.dragable = true` and bam u can drag the map.. I don't like this really..

It's not too terribly bad yet like the user enabling map drag and zoom isnt the worst thing in the world.. but still I'd like to disable this. Any ideas?

EDIT

Thanks all for the answers and comments. I guess I will just resort to not putting anything that can be turned malicious into my javascript, and do thing like pass my map variable to functions where necessary to slow people down.

Comment: You could wrap everything in a new function scope.

Comment: That said, there's really no reason to use globals. It would be better to alter your methods to take the map as a parameter where necessary.

Comment: Hmm... does this seem like better coding standards?

Answer (score 6):

You can use an immediately-invoked function (IIFE) expression to prevent your variables and functions from being exposed in the global scope:

```
var a = 10;

(function() {
    var b = 20;
})();
```

`window.a` lets you view and modify `a`, but you cannot do that with `b`:

[image]

[**Try it out here**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/BpCZ5/2/show/)

I'm more than sure that there's a way to edit `b` with Inspector, but I haven't taken the time to figure it out. Don't waste your time trying to prevent your users from modifying code that they can view.

Comment: Excellent point in your edit. Also, don't allow/expect sensitive data in JavaScript.

Comment: Link does not work

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Even if you wrap them into anonymous functions, user can get to them through debugger. As last resort he can simply intercept your traffic to his own machine and replace your JavaScript with something else.

Bottom line: JavaScript in browser is *client-side*. Client can do whatever he pleases with it.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing something like this:

```
(function(){
   //All of your current code
})();
```

One thing to still be aware of - Chrome developer tools also lets you edit the javascript (not the javascript file on the server, just currently running copy.) Go to Chrome Dev Tools->Sources and you can edit the javascript files.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Your saying you need to define your map globally, this means it's accessible for everyone.
You could define your map in a different scope and then only define the "public" things:

```
(function() {
    var map = new Map();
    window.myMap = {
        goTo: function(lat, lng) {
            map.goTo(lat, lng);
        }
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your architecture, there are a few ways to accomplish this. Use this method to create a reusable component that has public and private properties:

```
var protectedScope = function () {
    var protected_var = 'protected';
    this.showProtected = function () {
        return protected_var;
    }
    this.public = 'public';               
};
var myObject = new protectedScope();

console.log('Public var: '+myObject.public); // outputs "public"
console.log('Protected via accessor: '+myObject.showProtected ()); // outputs "private"
console.log('Protected var: '+myObject.protected); // outputs undefined
```

Any variable or function declared with a `var` keyword will be, in effect, private. Any variable or function that uses the `this.name` mechanism will be "public".

Understand that this structure is not truly public or private, such concepts are not a part of the language. There are still ways to get at those variables, and one can always view source. Just be clear; **this is a code organization concept** rather than a security concept. Chrome has had this developer console for a while, and other major user agents are moving to include similar tools (or already have done so). There are also tools like Firebug which allow a user full access to your javascript runtime environment. This isn't a realm that the developer can control at all.

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cf2kS/

**More Reading**

- "Private Members in JavaScript" by Douglas Crockford* - http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html
- *"OOP in JS, Part 1 : Public/Private Variables and Methods" on http://phrogz.net* -  http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS.html
- Javascript Object Management on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_School/JavaScript_Object_Management
- Closures on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: What if I edit protectedScope prototype and add my own custom getter, setter for private variables?

Comment: The thing about these pseudo-private variables is that you have to build any getter or setter into the main body of the code -- you can't use the prototype for accessing the pseudo-private variables. The reason this concept works at all is because you are forming closures in the function body. When you add or modify the function through its prototype, that code doesn't close the internal scope, so it has no access to variables in that scope. If you used `this.myVal = 1;` within the body, a prototype function can access it, but that's also exposed externally.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.defineProperty(map, 'zoom', {value:1});
```

or

```
Object.defineProperty(map, 'zoom',{
    set: function(){console.warn('Access denied!');},
    get: function(){return 1;}
    });
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/lajovewu/1/edit?js,console)

or

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'protect', {
    value:  function(ignore){
        var childObjects = [], ignore = ignore || [];
        ignore.push(this);      
        if(this instanceof MimeType)return; //Chrome Fix //window.clientInformation.mimeTypes[0].enabledPlugin[0] !== window.clientInformation.mimeTypes[0]
        for(var prop in this){
            if(typeof this[prop] === "unknown")continue; //IE fix
            if(this[prop] instanceof Object){
                var skip = false;
                for(var i in ignore)
                    if(ignore[i]===this[prop]){
                        skip = true;
                        break;
                    }
                if(!skip)childObjects.push(prop);   
            }       
            var d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, prop);
            if(!d || !d.configurable || !d.writable)continue;
            var that = this;
            (function(){
                var temp = that[prop];
                delete that[prop];
                Object.defineProperty(that, prop,{
                    set: function(){console.warn('Access denied!');},
                    get: function(){return temp;}
                });
            })();
        }
        for(var i = 0;i<childObjects.length;i++)
            this[childObjects[i]].protect(ignore);
    }  
});
this.onload=function(){this.protect();} //example
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/nadax/1)

Comment: hmm... so that would prevent users changing the zoom property then.. but wouldn't I then have to have a statement like that for EVERY property of EVERY global object? This gets me sorta there in preventing users changing the map zoom which actually is really good because if changing map zoom was terrible this would stop them, but still leaves the console and everything else

Comment: @user1759942 see the third method, that one protects **everything** cross-browser and not just from console, but also `javascript:xy` from the address bar.